Vuetify: Nested v-for for making lists in cards
I am attempting to create Recipe Card Components using data from a JSON file. I can successful get the cards to render with the correct data. However in the JSON file each recipe contains a nested array of ingredients. I am attempting to get the Ingredients to display as a list inside the recipe card.
This is the component html
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row v-for="recipe in recipes" :key="recipe.id" align-center>
      <v-col>
        <v-card
        class="mx-auto my-12"
        :recipe="recipe"
        max-width="374">
          <v-img
          class="align-end text-white"
          cover
          :src="recipe.image">
          </v-img>
          <v-card-title>
            {{ recipe.title }}
          </v-card-title>
          <v-row>
            <v-col dense cols="12">
              <v-list v-for="item in recpies.missedIngredients" :key="item.id">
                <v-list-subheader>
                  Missing Ingredients {{ recipe.missedIngredientCount }}
                </v-list-subheader>
                <v-list-item>
                  {{ item.name }}
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

And this is the script
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      recipes: {}
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/recipes')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => this.recipes = data)
    .catch(err => console.log(err.message))

  }
}
</script>

How can I succesfully access data from a nested array and render it as a list inside the cards?

I feel like a fool. After some tinkering I managed to figure it out.
Here is what my code now looks like:
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row v-for="recipe in recipes" :key="recipe.id" align-center>
      <v-col>
        <v-card
        class="mx-auto my-12"
        :recipe="recipe"
        max-width="374">
          <v-img
          class="align-end text-black"
          cover
          :src="recipe.image">
          <v-card-title>
            {{ recipe.title }}
          </v-card-title>
          </v-img>

          <v-row>
            <v-col dense cols="12">
              <v-list density="compact">
                <v-list-subheader>
                  Missing Ingredients {{ recipe.missedIngredientCount }}
                </v-list-subheader>
                <v-list-item v-for="item in recipe.missedIngredients"
                :key="item.id">
                {{ item.name }}
                </v-list-item>
              </v-list>
            </v-col>
            <v-col>

            </v-col>
          </v-row>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

